# Using Model Mapper to map and write to a list of DTOs

Tags: java, dto, data-transfer-objects, modelmapper

So I have been successful writing one record to a DTO created by model mapper, but am having trouble if I want to create a list of DTOs.

Here is my DTO (EDITED):

```
public class DirectoryDTO {
    String id;
    String personFirstName;
    String personLastName;
    String building;


public DirectoryDTO(String id, String personFirstName, String personLastName, String building) {
    this.id = id;
    this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
    this.personLastName = personLastName;
    this.building= building;
}


public DirectoryDTO() {

}
    //Getters and setter
}
```

my controller:

```
public List<DirectoryDTO> getTestDTO(){
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    List<DirectoryDTO> directoryDTO = ObjectMapperUtils.
        mapAll(directoryService.getDirectory("DD"), DirectoryDTO.class);

    return directoryDTO;
}
```

ObjectMapperUtils class:

```
public class ObjectMapperUtils {
  public static <D, T> List<D> mapAll(final Collection<T> entityList, Class<D> outClass) {
    return entityList
            .stream()
            .map(entity -> map(entity, outClass))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

The DTO that gets returned:

```
[
    {
        "id": null,
        "personFirstName": null,
        "personLastName": null,
        "building": null
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "personFirstName": null,
        "personLastName": null,
        "building": null
    },
....
]
```

The DTO has the correct number of rows, but obviously the data isn't being written to the object.

Full disclosure I copied the mapAll() function from somewhere and I am not sure if it is working as intended.

EDIT:

After hacking away a little more at it, I noticed that when I try to write to my DTO from an HQL query it refuses.  So let me post some more code.

Query:

```
query = em.createQuery(
        "select new dto.DirectoryDTO(p.id, p.firstName, p.lastName, p.hrper)  " +
                "  from Person p " +
                "join p.hrp hrp " +
                "left join p.pst ps " +
                "join pos.depts dept " +
                "where (trunc(:sysdate) between ps.StartDate AND ps.EndDate" +
                " OR (ps.StartDate <= trunc(:sysdate) AND ps.EndDate IS NULL)) " +
                "AND dept.deptsId = :department")
.setParameter("sysdate", getSysdate())
.setParameter("department", department));
```

All the joins should be set up correctly for these entities

Comment: could you show me the object class that `directoryService.getDirectory("DD")` return?

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda thanks for the reply. getDirectory() returns a List<Person> . Working through this I may have found an issue.  I didnt realize that if you are using an HQL query it throws up (or at least it seems).  I will post an edit with my new code

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda edited

Comment: first of all compare field names in DTO with Person filed names. They must be exactly the same if you didn't define any type maps or property maps.